# Scopes to separate polymorphic relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following DB relations in a Rails 4 project

```
class Hat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale, as: product
end

class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale, as: product
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, polymorphic: true

  scope :hats, -> { ??? }
  scope :shoes, -> { ??? }
end
```

Given an `@sale` object, how could I get all the products, that belong a specific model, like `Hat` or `Shoe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `product_type` in your tables (see [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) for more info), so I'd do a query on that:

```
scope :hats, -> { where(product_type: Hat.name) }
# Not sure that this `Hat.class.name` is the actual value in the table, 
# so you might aswell check in your DB what's the correct value.
```

Comment: `Hat.class.name` renders `Class`